# Passing a collection via JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, json, linq

I am calling the following action from Jquery. When I look at the "data" values it shows the expected information, including the collection of addresses. But when I pass this as JSon to my JQuery the Addresses collection is empty. Is it possible to pass a collection within My JSon data?

```
 [AcceptVerbs("get")]
    public ActionResult GetInstitutions(string term)
    {
        var data = ( from i in db.Institutions
            .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(term))
            let pa = i.Addresses.Take(5)                     
            select new { 
                i.ID, 
                value = i.Name, 
                i.Website
                ,Addresses = pa
             })
            .Take(10).ToArray();

            JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None, jsSettings));
    }
```

From this JQuery:

```
  $(".autocompleteInst").autocomplete({
            source: "@Url.Action("GetInstitutions", "Institution")",
            minLength: 3,
            delay: 100,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.Addresses[0].Street1);                                
            }
        });
```

** Update **
I added some JSon configuration code to my example that I had left out originally. I'm pretty sure the ReferenceLoopHandling settings is causing the problem. Any ideas of a way to set the serializer to only go one level deep on loops?

Comment: can you change the ActionResult to JsonResult and return new JsonResult{ data = data}; instead ?

Comment: Re. the above; `JsonResult` inherits from `ActionResult`, so you don't need to change the return type. It should also be `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Have you watched the requests in Fiddler to see (1) if requests are being made to your service at all and (2) what kind of data is being returned?

Comment: Yes, And I'm not seeing the "addresses" collection being passed. I'm now 99% sure it's because of the "ReferenceLoopHandling" setting.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Addresses`?

Comment: ICollection<Address>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your Address class looks like. But, make sure `pa` is serializable. You can do the following:

```
select new {
       id = i.ID,
       value = i.Name,
       website = i.Website,
       addresses = pa.Select(x => new { addr_id: x.Id, addr_name: x.Name }) //Whatever items you want
}
```

The above one would be an easy option. Another option would be to use DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) which are serializable. For example -

```
class AddressDTO
{
   int Id {get; set;}
   int Name {get; set;}

   AddressDTO(Address addr)
   {
      this.Id = addr.Id;
      this.Name = addr.Name;
   }
}
```

And then you can select them like this -

```
select new {
           id = i.ID,
           value = i.Name,
           website = i.Website,
           addresses = pa.Select(x => new AddressDTO(x))
    }
```

Or.. you can use libraries like NewtonSoft which makes things super easy. All you'll have to do is drop [JsonProperty] attribute when you define your properties in the Address class. Something like this -

```
public class Address
{
   [JsonProperty]
   public string Name;
}
```

And you can hand off the Address object to be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
      select new { 
            i.ID, 
            value = i.Name, 
            i.Website
            ,Addresses = pa.ToArray()
         })
        .Take(10).ToArray();
```